# Confusion with function "InverseFunction"

Tags: functions

Run codes below

```
InverseFunction /@ {InverseFunction, List, Reverse, RotateLeft, RotateRight, Sequence}
```

and one is returned with

```
{InverseFunction^(-1), #1 &, #1 &, #1 &, #1 &, #1 &}
```

For the first one, at least a formal answer is given (even though I hoped it gave something like `InverseFunction` itself); however for the rest it does not make sense that an identity function is obtained.

Ideally, `Reverse` is the inverse function of itself, and `RotateRight` and `RotateLeft` are inverse functions to each other.

Is it a bug?

Comment: Since this behavior also appears in *Mathematica* 10.1 I am removing the version tag.

Answer (score 2):

I have never considered applying [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html) to Symbols such as these so I appreciate the question.

I hypothesize that, without a specifically defined inverse, the Symbol is tested on an arbitrary argument, e.g. `Reverse[foo]`.  Since each of these heads do not actually do anything in such a case (other than issue a Message) they appear inert, and `# &` is a reasonable inverse of an inert function I suppose.  Why this evaluation takes place rather than returning e.g. `InverseFunction[Reverse]` I don't know.

This idea seems plausible based the [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint.html), e.g.

```
InverseFunction[Reverse]; // TracePrint
```

> (Reverse^(-1))
>
> InverseFunction
>
> Reverse
>
> Reverse
>
> Reverse[Solve`InvFVar[0]]
>
> Reverse
>
> Solve`InvFVar[0]
>
> Solve`InvFVar
>
> 0
>
> Solve`InvFVar[0]
>
> Solve`InvFVar
>
> 0
>
> #1&
>
> Function

Wherein `` Solve`InvFVar[0] `` looks like the arbitrary argument I supposed.

Comment: Will it be possible to incorporate it as built-in functionality that, say, `InverseFunction[RotateLeft]` returns `RotateRight` in the future?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ I am not a Wolfram Research developer, so if you are asking about "from the factory" functionality I have no idea.  If you mean can one modify `InverseFunction` so that it will return that, yes, easily, but it may not be wise to do so.  Try this if you care to: `Unprotect[InverseFunction];
InverseFunction[RotateLeft] := RotateRight;
InverseFunction[RotateRight] := RotateLeft;
Protect[InverseFunction];`

Comment: Wizard Is it possible to use something like `UpSet` or `TagSet`?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ For Protected functions like `RotateRight` you would need to them (`RotateRight`) to use `TagSet`, but if you prefer that to unprotecting `InverseFunction` it's certainly an option.